# Repeating a Float Up animation on TextView

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `Button` that can be pressed an infinite number of times. When pressed, I show a `+1` above the `Button` and then use an `Animation` to Float the `TextView` up and disappear. This all works good. My problem happens when a user repeatedly taps the `Button`. If the `Animation` is still in progress and floating up, the `TextView`'s position will reset and the `Animation` will restart.

How can I continuously allow the `Animation` to finish while starting another `Animation` on the same `TextView`? I guess my best example of what I want would be a game where you collect coins and each time one is collected you see a +1 float up above a character.

**float_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromYDelta="90%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

**MainActivity.Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private long voteMultiplier = 1;
private TextView txtNoNumber;
private Animation fadeInAnimation;
private Button buttonNo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.float_up);

    buttonNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_no);

    buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            voteNo();

        }
    });
}

private void voteNo() {
    txtNoNumber.setText(String.format("%s%s", "+ ", voteMultiplier));
    txtNoNumber.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_add));
    txtNoNumber.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);

 }
}
```

My `Button` and `TextView` are defined in my `activity_main.xml`. There is nothing special about them.

Thank you.

Comment: If you dont want to "jump" from the current animation to the last usefull animation you will need to implement a sort of animations queue, where you add animations to the queue if an animation is currently playing and then play them consequently

Comment: For this purpose you will be better off using Canvas and SurfaceView. That way you can draw text and add whatever animations you want by altering alpha and position of the drawn text. And you can have as many as you want

Comment: @Drew Please try my answer and let me know the result. Thank you

Comment: @LunarWatcher Thanks for the reply. I'm rather new to Android and I'm wondering if you have any examples or a link to a tutorial? I've been trying to implement this action using a `SurfaceView` and `Canvas` but I'm having a tough time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following works but I can't say that it is really the best way. I think the `Canvas` and `SurfaceView` suggestion would be more robust.

The issue that you are having is that the animation occurs on the view and there is only one view that is moved during animation. That is why it resets and you can only see one rising number at a time. The following solution creates a stack of `gone` views that sit on top of the underlying view that shows. The IDs for these views are kept in an array that is cycled through. When the button is clicked, the next `gone` view is made visible and animated. At the end of the animation, the view is made `gone` again.

Here is a little video of the effect:

[Demo video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMozz.gif)

I have exaggerated the movement to show better in the video.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private long voteMultiplier = 1;
    private int[] txtNoNumber = new int[5];
    private Button buttonNo;
    private int animIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_no);
        txtNoNumber[0] = R.id.txtNoNumber1;
        txtNoNumber[1] = R.id.txtNoNumber2;
        txtNoNumber[2] = R.id.txtNoNumber3;
        txtNoNumber[3] = R.id.txtNoNumber4;
        txtNoNumber[4] = R.id.txtNoNumber5;

        buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                voteNo();

            }
        });
    }

    private void voteNo() {
        TextView tv;
        Animation fadeInAnimation;

        if (animIndex >= txtNoNumber.length) {
            animIndex = 0;
        }
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(txtNoNumber[animIndex]);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv.setText(String.format("%s%s", "+ ", voteMultiplier++));
//        txtNoNumber.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_add));
        fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.float_up);
        fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener(tv));
        tv.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
        animIndex++;
    }

    private class MyAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        View mView;

        MyAnimationListener(View view) {
            mView = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.floatanimation.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNoNumber1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.319" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNoNumber2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.319" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNoNumber3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.319" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNoNumber4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.319" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNoNumber5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.319" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank for the detailed post. I'll mark this as the answer if I can't figure out the `SurfaceView` and `Canvas` example. I'm rather new to Android and I'm having a difficult time at understanding how to implement them.

Comment: @Drew Using `SurfaceView`/`Canvas` will be more involved, but you may be able to find some good examples to guide you. Since you are animating a `View`, the way I posited is appropriate IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add `AnimationListener` to your animation `fadeInAnimation`.

**2.** Add an extra variable `voteCount`  to count the `button` click.

**3.** In `onClick()` method, call `voteNo()` method only for `first` time to start animation and for others handle it from `onAnimationEnd()` method.

**3.** Inside `onAnimationEnd()` method, check the value of `voteCount`. If `value` is greater than `0` then call `voteNo()` method to start animation again.

**Here is the working code:**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener{

    private long voteMultiplier = 1;
    private TextView txtNoNumber;
    private Animation fadeInAnimation;
    private Button buttonNo;

    int voteCount  = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.float_up);
        fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);

        txtNoNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_no_number);
        buttonNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_no);

        buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                voteCount++;

                if (voteCount == 1)
                    voteNo();
            }
        });
    }

    private void voteNo() {
        txtNoNumber.setText(String.format("%s%s", "+ ", voteMultiplier));
        txtNoNumber.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        txtNoNumber.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        if (animation == fadeInAnimation) {
            voteCount--;

            if (voteCount > 0)
                voteNo();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks a lot, but wouldn't this just build a queue and show them one after the other instead of showing them when the user clicks the button?

Comment: Yes its working like a queue. If user clicks on button frequently, it will show animation one by one. I have tested it and its working fine.

Comment: of course, It will show animation during button clicking time and also show animation when you stop clicking.